# Genetic algorithm(finding expression using digits and operators)

Tags: genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming, genetic

I have the following genetic programming problem(Homework):
I need to use 5 digits (0 to 9) and any operators(+,-,*,/) to generate a expression to give me the answer as 30. Can anyone please explain how can I go about solving this using genetic programming?

Comment: (1 + 2 + 3)(5) + 0

Comment: Sounds like a fun homework problem. Do it. Presumably your text explains how such things work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,it's a genetic programing(GP) problem.You can google it for more details.

In GP,each individual represents one  computer program,which is represented using a tree structure.In your problem ,it represents a mathematical expression.The tree in follow picture can represent a individual of expression ‘3.4-x’ .

[image]

The leaf node is chose from your digital set,and non-leaf node from operator set.

Then,you can choose some crossover and mutation operators to evolve your expression.

For a crossover operator,you can select one random node in each of the two parents,then swap the corresponding subtrees to create the two oﬀspring as illustrated in next figure.

[image]

Also,there are many corresponding mutation operators.For example,randomly choose a node to change the digital or operators.